# `coordinates` attribute of a netcdf variable is missing in xarray

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray

I have a netcdf variable, namely `mesh2d_sa1` which contains an attribute `coordinates`.  But when I tried to call this attribute by `ds.mesh2d_sa1.attrs["coordinates"]`, it is not found.  The following is an extract of the output of `ncdump -h xxxxxxx.nc`, which confirms the existence of the attribute of `coordinates`.

```
double mesh2d_sa1(time, mesh2d_nFaces, mesh2d_nLayers) ;
    mesh2d_sa1:mesh = "mesh2d" ;
    mesh2d_sa1:location = "face" ;
    mesh2d_sa1:coordinates = "mesh2d_face_x mesh2d_face_y" ;
    mesh2d_sa1:cell_methods = "mesh2d_nFaces: mean" ;
    mesh2d_sa1:standard_name = "sea_water_salinity" ;
    mesh2d_sa1:long_name = "Salinity in flow element" ;
    mesh2d_sa1:units = "1e-3" ;
    mesh2d_sa1:grid_mapping = "wgs84" ;
    mesh2d_sa1:_FillValue = -999. ;
```

Comment: This seems like something that might be interpreted by xarray as indicating the array structure rather than being an actual metadata attribute. What does your dataset look like after reading? E.g. `print(ds)`

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I find out the solution.  The `coordinate` attribute is saved in `ds.mesh2d_sa1.encoding['coordinates']`.    IMO, the `coordinate` attribute should also be saved in `ds.mesh2d_sa1.attrs`.

Comment: Have you checked if the raw data is  CF-compliant? If it isn't and it isn't ideally constructed then xarray failing to parse something properly is to be expected

Comment: @RobertWilson I can see the CF-1.8 attribute in the netcdf file.  So it should be CF-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinate attribute can be accessed via `ds.mesh2d_sa1.encoding['coordinates']`